# I feel like I don't have enough options when reviewing low quality posts

Tags: discussion, review-queue

Take a look at [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124480/13418).

- It certainly does not "Look OK".
- I can't edit it because I don't know anything about Halo.
- I wouldn't recommend deletion because I think the author can improve it.
- Should I just skip it ?

I took time to leave a comment to indicate to the answerer what he should do. It seems unfair to just skip it in the end.

What is the correct course of action ?

Comment: As someone who is familiar with Halo, I can't figure out how that answer addresses the question at all. It feels like the poster put it on the wrong question by accident.

Comment: In this case of that particular post, it wasn't an answer to the question ("what would be the effect of the guns hitting a planet?" - "the guns don't fire at full power", so I converted it to a comment. +1 for your general point about there not being enough options in the LQP review queue, which I agree with; however, that's an issue for [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com), since the working of the review queues is common to all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @RandalThor that's worth an answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First off, **you should *always* seriously consider skipping**, especially if you know nothing about the property in question. Skipping isn't the mark of failure, it's simply a way of saying that you genuinely think that someone else might be able to objectively assess the answer better than you can.

So what are your remaining options?

**Looks OK** - Not appropriate. Even a cursory glance shows that the answer doesn't address the key point raised (e.g. *what would happen?*) and while it's perfectly acceptable to disagree with the main thesis of a question, you need to explain (in pretty solid detail) why the question's assumptions are wrong.

**Edit the Answer** - Not appropriate. You don't know anything about Halo and anything you add (beyond fixing grammar and spelling) would be sheer guesswork.

**Mark for Deletion** - This is the correct option. In its current state, the answer simply doesn't address the question. Once it's deleted, It's not gone forever and the OP can still improve it further and vote for it to be reopened. If you're genuinely in agony, you can always leave a comment.

---

As it happens, one of your friendly mods has already converted the question into a comment, where it belongs.

Comment: I agree with this; I've skipped more times than I've taken an action on the LQ queue, better to leave it to someone who *can* make a good review than do a half-arsed one.