# Why can't I review posts anymore?

Tags: support, review-queue

I went to review queue and I was confronted with a message:

[image]

Obviously it says I have been selecting `No Action Needed`, which I have, b/c on all the questions or answers it only provides `No Action Needed` or `Skip`. I didn't want to skip the post as I was there to make a review, so I just selected `No Action Needed`. Maybe if you were given more of a choice ,b/c right now this is really counter intuitive. I thought `No Action Needed` , means no action is needed by me as someone has taken care of the issue, which is why other choices are now not there when they normally are.

What is the point of the `Skip` button? The more I think about it, the more ridiculous I think this is, why even bother have someone check a question if all you can do is skip it???

Comment: Can you give an example of a First Post review where your only options were "No action needed" or "Skip". I can't check right now as the queue is empty, but I believe I usually have the ability to edit the post, add a comment, upvote it, downvote it or flag it; after that I can choose "No action needed", "I'm done", or "Skip".

Comment: @Blackwood some that he chose "no action needed": [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158425/5184), [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158413/5184), [3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158418/5184) . the third has been deleted, so not everyone can see it, but it was a non-answer that only asked a new question.

Comment: @MolagBal, of coarse I clicked on it. Still does not explain why there is only `Skip` or `No Action Needed`?

Comment: Why would you have a button for "I'm Done" until you *do* something? Until you do something, those are the two valid choices - "Nothing needs to be done here" or "I don't want to do anything".

Comment: @phantom42, I don't want a button for  "I'm Done" , the logical outlay would be, `No Action Needed` and `Recommend Deletion` and `Skip` if you can't decide.

Comment: But....you can flag it for deletion, and once you do, you get the "I'm Done" button.

Comment: @phantom42, Where is that? Sometimes I get it and others I don't.

Comment: It's not one of the button actions on "First Post", it's right under the text of the question where question actions always are. "Recommend deletion" is a button action on the Low Quality queue.

Comment: [see the "flag" to the left of the modal?](http://imgur.com/zOXLj26). click that and choose NAA, or whatever. then you get [the "i'm done button](http://imgur.com/Ljzhbf2)

Comment: @phantom42, but it has already been flagged to get to this point, so why flag it again?

Comment: @MolagBal, I am talking about Low quality posts.

Comment: You only have one item in the [recent low quality review queue history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history), and you clicked *recommend deletion*. Going back 5 pages, you hit "looks ok" 4 times out of 13 reviews.

Comment: I am overly surprised that a 10k user does not know how the review queue works..

Comment: @Gnemlock, see this question of mine, https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9890/is-there-an-explanation-of-duties-for-each-milestone . And I still don't know how things work.

Comment: Note that, while there are "best practices" that may be unique to a site (say, here, for example), you might find some help on the [Stack Exchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Its like SciFi, but specific to using the Stack Exchange sites. May be useful.

Comment: [Item in the LQ review queue](http://imgur.com/QSCX9dk) - it always has the "delete" option.

Comment: It also says your "not good at english"; on the contrary, your better than *a lot* of users I see on here (though I tend to dwell more on IT-related exchanges). Read up on it. Use the help guidelines. If your not sure, ask in chat, ask in meta, ask in the linked meta. With the uptmost respect, if you still don't understand, I would suggest limiting your use of the feature. It seems clear that that should *not* be the case. @phantom42, low quality reviews have that option, as they have already been flagged as potential deletion candidates. First posts, for example, do not have this option.

Comment: @Gnemlock Yes, but Kylo has said in the comments that this all concerns the LQ review queue, and that it doesn't always have the button (despite the screenshot and language in the question all being related to the FP queue).

Comment: You may be interested in: [I feel like I don't have enough options when reviewing low quality posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9431/21267)

Answer (score 16):

In that dialog, you are expected to do *something* to the post you're reviewing. You have all the same options you do when looking at a post outside review, and once you do, the review is considered "finished". From the Review help page:

> In these queues, you can edit the post, flag it, upvote or downvote it, add a comment, or upvote a previously existing comment. When you take one of these actions, the "I'm Done" button becomes enabled, allowing you to complete the review.

"No Action Needed" means that there is literally *nothing* you can do about the post to indicate it's quality -- it's not worthy of an upvote, but there's nothing wrong with it to justify a downvote or flag, and it can't be improved by an edit. That's a pretty rare case, so if you do it too often (in particular, if you "pass over" things that other reviewers have issues with), it will stick out as odd, and eventually you may draw a temporary review ban.

If someone else has already been there and "fixed" the post, consider upvoting it. If someone else has already left a comment pointing out something that could be improved, you can upvote that comment to indicate agreement. "No Action Needed" is really a last resort.

The "Skip" button exists for cases where you don't feel like you can accurately judge a post's quality. This happens more on larger sites where judging quality can depend heavily on, e.g. how much you know about a given programming language (e.g. "is this even realistic code" type of things); on SF/F, that does still happen but it's less common. The Skip button basically means "I don't want to do this review at all", and you don't get credit for it in your review stats.

Comment: Skipping is not doing anything??? So how are you supposed to do something when the only choice is `Skip` if the post is bad. No point flagging it again. I don't get it???

Comment: Wow, is there nothing I can't get banned from? What other features can you get banned from?

Comment: @MolagBal is right. There's no "review score" which can drop too low; on sites without an audit system, review bans have to be applied manually.

Answer (score 9):

> Why can't I review posts anymore?

Because your review privileges have been temporarily revoked, due to a series of bad reviews.

56 of your 57 First Posts reviews have been "No Action Needed", which is a warning sign in itself since *some* kind of action is usually appropriate. (You can review your reviews [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history?userId=65457) - note that this link works only for you and mods.) And upon looking more closely, [some](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/104382) of your [reviews](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/103943) were "No Action Needed" on *non-answers*, where the appropriate course of action would be flagging.

Some of your Close Votes reviews have also been inappropriate: you [voted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/104371) to [leave open](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/104370) a couple of story-ID questions contrary to [our established policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/31394). I assume this is simply because you weren't aware of the policy, and no harm was done in these cases, but now you know.

> on all the questions or answers it only provides`No Action Needed` or `Skip`. I didn't want to skip the post as I was there to make a review, so I just selected `No Action Needed`.

This remark displays a very worryingly poor understanding of the way the review system works. If the only actual review you could make was "No Action Needed", then **what would be the point of having the review queue at all?** You should have realised that you were misunderstanding the system if you thought there was only one possibility for actually reviewing the post. What you should be doing when reviewing First Posts or Late Answers is **taking some action on the post** (e.g. voting, flagging, editing, commenting) and only clicking "No Action Needed" if, well, no action is needed. Once you've taken some action, even if it be as simple as upvoting a comment, the "No Action Needed" button will disappear and an "I'm Done" button will appear instead.

> but it has already been flagged to get to this point, so why flag it again?

No. In the First Posts review queue, ***every* post by a completely new user shows up for review.** The point is that new users are never supposed to be posting into a vacuum, and always get some kind of feedback on their post, which makes them more likely to stick around if the post is good. Same for Late Answers - *every* new answer to an old question shows up there.

You may be getting mixed up with the Low Quality Posts review queue, in which answers do indeed have to be flagged in order to appear. But in that queue there's no "No Action Needed" option; you can either click "Looks OK" or "Recommend Deletion".

Another important point about First Posts and Late Answers is that **you're the only person to review them** - a single review is enough to remove them from the queue. That's why it's particularly important that you review these carefully - an inappropriate "No Action Needed" could result in non-answers or spam remaining on the site unnoticed.

### [Please read this guidance on reviewing First Posts and Late Answers.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10607/31394)

Comment: The link to "[first post reviews](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history?userId=65457)" seems to go to my own reviews regardless of the user ID

Comment: @Valorum Yes, that link is visible only to Kylo himself and moderators.

Comment: So, no warning, no mentoring people when you see something is not right? Just drop the hammer? Like I commented earlier, is there nothing I can't get banned from?

Comment: I will say it right now, the only time I have used the `Skip` button was when I did not know what was being asked, so I skipped it. Am I the only one who literally takes what each button means. And you just further making me wonder why there is a reveiw queue anyway??? Especially when "Skip" means `to pass over or omit` I was doing my duty and reviewing the post, so naturally, "No Action Needed" is the only button left, so that is what I clicked. You guys need to work on your naming of controls. If I named a button, skip in a UI I made , I would expect the user to use it to omit something.

Comment: @KyloRen Your warning is a temporary review ban. You'll be able to review again in 6 days.

Comment: What else is there? I see a couple of grayed out buttons, "Skip" and "No Action Needed"

Comment: @KyloRen OK, I edited again for clarity. "Skip" does indeed mean to pass over or omit, and "No Action Needed" is **not** the only possibility left - *once you've done something*, the "I'm Done" button will show up instead of "No Action Needed". (All of this should have been made clear in the guidance that appeared to you when you were new to reviewing.)

Comment: I just went on SO and looked at the review queue and the explanation is collapsed. I had no idea you could do all that to a first post. I always clicked "No Action Needed", remembered the name of the question, closed the queue and went to the question from the questions tab and flagged it or made a comment.

Comment: @KyloRen We live and learn :-)

Comment: So why no guidance from the mods?

Comment: @KyloRen This answer right here is guidance from a mod. The review-ban message which you've screenshotted in your question is guidance from a mod, and links you to a [meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10607/31394) which contains more guidance from a mod.

Comment: OK, just checking, ban first ask questions later. Great policy.

Comment: Or maybe, if it was so confusing to you, ask questions first, click "no action needed" later.

Comment: @phantom42, do you make it a habit to ask questions when you think you are doing something correctly? Me personally, I tend to ask questions when I don't know if I am doing something correctly.

Comment: You've indicated repeatedly that you did not understand the interface or the options, even saying that the guidance should have been clearer. That's a good time to ask for some clarification. *Could/Should* have mods stepped in earlier? With the record that Rand mentioned, I'd agree with you - someone *should* have said something to you long ago - but you could have asked too.